# Get element if other element contains text

Tags: xpath

I have a list with html blocks that looks like this.

```
 <div class="blocklist">
        <div id="rule">Ipsum Int</div>
        <div>
<button class="trashcan"></button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocklist">
        <div id="rule">Ipsum Int2</div>
        <div>
<button class="trashcan"></button></div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to match the class **trashcan** with the text from **id rule**

I have tried different contains and or with XPath but no luck so far.
But though that something like this could work

```
//*[@id='rule' and contains(text(),'Ipsum Int')]////following-sibling::button[1]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see no elements with class `"btn-trashcan"` in provided HTML-sample. Also share how you tried and clarify what do you mean by *match the class with the text*

Comment: @JaSON yeah. sorry it was a typo. fixed that and added a hint on what I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for good alternatives. found a solution with `following-sibling`

```
//*[@id='rule' and contains(text(),'Ipsum Int')]//following-sibling::div[2]//button
```

Answer (score 1):

A button will only function with the context of a form, you can have either a form around the whole thing or create a form per button. Or alternatively you can use a onclick event on the button.
In case of the form the easiest option is to add the name and value properties to the button, this value will be sent to server when clicking the specific button. With onclick the identifier can be in the target urll.

Ow, and I noticed you have multiple elements with id=rule, id's should always be unique

Comment: yes you are completely right about unique ideas. though this is a very small internal app so its ok with the same id's :)